# I have null field but retrofit dont send to backend

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have class like this:

```
class MyData {

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("surName")
    var surName: String? = null
    
}
```

My service calls is like this.

```
interface MyServiceCall {
    
    @PUT("/My/endPoint")
    fun updateInfo(@Body info: MyData): Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>>

}
```

But when I want to send only name and surname null. The null dont go to backend and then return 400 - Bad Request.

So my question is How can I send data to backend even fields are null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply `serializeNulls()` in `GsonBuilder()` when adding converterFactory for Retrofit object :

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("YOUR BASE URL")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))
    .build();
```

Comment: How can I add `seializeNulls()` for a specific function?

Comment: You have to create another retrofit client with this config to utilize it for such API calls ORyou should use overriden JsonBody like    
        val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
            JSONObject(
                GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().toJson(
                    PrdUpdatePOJO(
                        target = null
                    )
                )
            ).toString()
        )